# Can not build simple project in freshly installed Android Studio 0.8.9, "Gradle project sync failed."

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I just installed the latest version of Android Studio (0.8.9) but I am not able to run a simple default application, just created from the 'New Project' wizard.
When I try to Run the application I get an error saying:

> "Gradle 'Testets' project refresh failed
>   Error:Operation timed out. If you are behind an HTTP proxy, please configure the proxy >settings either in IDE or Gradle."

If I try to Clean or Rebuild the project, I get an error saying:

> Information:Gradle tasks [clean, :]
>   Error:A problem occurred configuring root project 'Testets'.
>   Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
>   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.2.
>        Required by:
>            :Testets:unspecified
>   Could not GET   'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/0.12.2/gradle-0.12.2.pom'.
>   Connection to http://jcenter.bintray.com refused
>   Information:BUILD FAILED
>   Information:Total time: 1 mins 15.745 secs
>   Information:1 error
>   Information:0 warnings
>   Information:See complete output in console

I found these similar problems while searching, but none really contain a solution.
[Gradle project sync failed. Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25614492/gradle-project-sync-failed-android-studio)
[android studio can't build project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25749579/android-studio-cant-build-project)

The only clue I can find is that there is some networking issue. I tried doing it at home and in school, and neither "should" have any problems. I disabled the firewall on my computer as well.

If this is really a networking issue, how can I go about to find out that it is that for sure?
Any other ideas on what might be causing the problem?

I am running AS on OSX 10.9.4.

Many thanks.
/R

Comment: try to access the url from your web-browser just make sure these are accessible there. Let me know if this is the case .

Comment: @pyus13 None of the urls are accessible. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: then it doesn't seems and Studio issue, its more related to your Network. Are you under proxy or some restricted network ?

Comment: @pyus13 No I am not behind a proxy. I am currently on a regular home network so there is no restrictions, at least that I know of. Do you have any idea of how I might be able to check it, either way?

Comment: @pyus13 Seems like I am able to reach them from an free online proxy though. So I think it is safe to say that there is a networking issue now.

Comment: ya its your network issue only, so are you problem got solved now. Once you are able to access these via browser give a try to Studio.

Comment: @pyus13 After I uninstalled LogMeInHamachi on my computer I was able to run my project. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @rafaul great, enjoy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of @pyus13 I was able to conclude that it was indeed a connectivity issue that created the errors.
After uninstalling LogMeInHamachi on my machine I was able to run AS as normal. I uninstalled just of suspicion and there was nothing that was really pointing towards that as the problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Android Studio is still a build version. This problem is fixed in **gradle v1.11** please update your gradle version and try creating new project. For first time it will take more time to download and setup gradle. So be patience till it updates. Check out the gradle versions [here](http://www.gradle.org/downloads)

Comment: This does not seem to be working out for me. I followed [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21297113/1354545) to update Gradle, but with v1.11 instead. I am getting the same errors as before.

Comment: I know it's bit difficult to do. It will eat your head. But you need try something out with latest version. If it is not working out. I recommend you to download Android Studio again with latest version of Gradle will solve the issue. Finally i did this and it worked will for me.

Comment: This does not solve it for me, there seems to be a networking problem going on. I think that there is something locally on my computer that is messing things up.
Thanks for your help!